# what is the difference between .navbar-right and .pull-right in bootstrap v3.3.7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

what is the difference between .navbar-right and .pull-right and in which case should i use each one of them?

```
<header class="container">
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a href="." class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="nav"><a href=".">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav"><a href=".">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li  class="nav"><a href=".">Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

in this code as is, the ( Item 1,Item 2,Item 3)will align to the right
but if i replace the "pull-right" with "navbar-right", the ( Item 1,Item 2,Item 3)will align to the left..Do not they have the same effect?
by the way, what is the difference between .navbar-right and .pull-right and in which case should i use each one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `pull-right` defined as

```
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}
```

That means it floating elements right position of the screen.

And `navbar-right` defined as

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-right {
    float: right!important;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

That means it will only apply if only avaiable screen width is 768px, also it applies -15px margin in right.